# not convergent in norm

Tags: normed-spaces

I want to show that $u_n(x)=sin(2nx)$ is not strongly convergent in $L^p(0, \pi)$
The problem is that I don't have a candidate function. If I pick $0$ then for p larger than 2 it is hard to calculate the integral of $sin(2nx)$ raised to the $p$th power. There has to be an easier way. What is an elegant way of showing there is no strong convergence?

Answer (score 0):

If $(u_n)$ were norm-convergent, then there would be an a.e. pointwise convergent subsequence $(u_{n_k})$. And since $m(\mathbb P)=\pi>0,$ there must then be an irrational number $0<\alpha<\pi$ for which $(\sin n_k\alpha) $ converges, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for $p \geq 2$: Holder's inequality tells us that if $u_n$ converges in $L^{p}$ then it converges in $L^{2}$ also. This implies that $\int_0^{\pi} |\sin (2nx)-\sin (2mx)|^{2}dx \to 0$ as $ n,m \to \infty$. But you can evaluate this explicitly and see that this is false.

Proof for $0<p<2$: Due to boundedness of $u_n$'s convergence in $L^{P}$ implies convergence in $L^{2}$: $\int_0^{\pi} |\sin (2nx)-\sin (2mx)|^{2}dx \leq 2^{2-p}\int_0^{\pi} |sin (2nx)-\sin (2mx)|^{p}dx $.